# What is the TDPID when i connect SAS to teradata installed on my machine

Tags: sas, teradata

What is the TDPID when i connect SAS to teradata installed on my machine
i am using the following code to connect SAS to teradata:
enter code here

```
proc sql; 
options symbolgen;
CONNECT TO Teradata as tdm 
( 
schema=127.0.0.1 
user=&tdusr. 
password=&tdpwd. 
defer=yes 
tdpid=127.0.0.1 
mode = teradata 
);
```

and i m getting this error:
ERROR: The TERADATA engine cannot be found.
ERROR: A Connection to the Teradata DBMS is not currently supported, or is not installed at your site.

and the teradata is installed :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says you don't have "SAS Access to Teradata" in your SAS installation. Also you need to have it licensed.

Comment: yeah i figured it out eventually thanx for u r support though